# Using RegEx within Yii 2's UrlManager rules, doesn't work

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-urlmanager

Yii2 urlManager, I want to write a regex that looks like below.

`*.*com/bj/haidian/` is good.

`*.*com/bj/haidian` does not work.

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            "<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>" => "<controller>/<action>",
            "<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>" => "<controller>/<action>",
            '<module:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/index',
            'bj|sh|gz|sz|cd|xa|wh|hz|tj|dl/?'=>'/sem/weight',
            'bj|sh|gz|sz|cd|xa|wh|hz|tj|dl/<district:[0-9a-zA-Z\_\-]+>/?' => '/sem/weight',
            'bj|sh|gz|sz|cd|xa|wh|hz|tj|dl/<district:[0-9a-zA-Z\_]+>/<cond:[0-9a-zA-Z\_]+>/?' => '/sem/weight',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: can I see your htaccess ?

Answer (score 1):

Your rules should be before the `default` rules or `parameterized` routes not after them otherwise your rules work fine on my side I just tested all 3 of them, just change the sequence to the following.

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'bj|sh|gz|sz|cd|xa|wh|hz|tj|dl/?'=>'/sem/weight',
            'bj|sh|gz|sz|cd|xa|wh|hz|tj|dl/<district:[0-9a-zA-Z\_\-]+>/?' => '/sem/weight',
            'bj|sh|gz|sz|cd|xa|wh|hz|tj|dl/<district:[0-9a-zA-Z\_]+>/<cond:[0-9a-zA-Z\_]+>/?' => '/sem/weight',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            "<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>" => "<controller>/<action>",
            "<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>" => "<controller>/<action>",
            '<module:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/index',

        ],
    ],
```